# Fabricate Frequently Factored Functions

Tags: code-golf, math, open-ended-function

In  one of [this question's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141315/what-an-odd-function) bonuses I asked you to design a permutation on the natural numbers such that the probability of a random term being odd was \$1\$.  Now let's kick it up a notch.  I want you to design and implement a permutation, \$f\$, on the natural numbers such that, for every integer \$n\$ greater than 0, the probability on \$f\$ of a member being divisible by \$n\$ is \$1\$.

#### Definition of Probability

To avoid confusion or ambiguity I am going to clearly lay out what is meant by probability in this question.  This is adapted directly from my original question.

Let us say we have a function \$f\$ and a predicate \$P\$.  The probability of a number fulfilling \$P\$ will be defined as the limit of the number of members of \$f\{1..n\}\$ fulfilling the predicate \$P\$ divided by \$n\$.

Here it is in a nice Latex formula

$$
  \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\left|\left\{x : x\in \left\{1\dots n\right\}\right\},P(f(x))\right|}{n}
$$

---

In order to have a probability of something being \$1\$ you don't need every member to satisfy the predicate, you just need the ones that don't to get farther apart the bigger they are.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so answers will be scored in bytes with less bytes being better.

You may take the natural numbers to either include or exclude 0.  Both are fine.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
!uΣz:NCNmΠN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkPuoqfHhjsWmBv8VS88trrLyc/bLPbfA7/9/AA) Or [showing the stats for the first `100` n in the first `5000` terms](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6v4Htivb6pgYGB8qFlD3csNjQweNQ2EcR/1NT4v/Tc4iorP2e/3HML/P7/BwA)

#### Explanation

```
        mΠ     Map factorial over 
          N    the Natural numbers
      CN       Cut into lists of lengths corresponding to the natural numbers
   z:N         ZipWith append the natural numbers and ^
  Σ            Concatenate into one list
 u             Remove duplicates
!              Index
```

#### Proof (Without the `u`)

For triangle numbers : `f(½n*(n+1))=n`

Otherwise : `f(n)=k!` for some `k`.

As the density of triangular numbers is zero, this has the same probability as the sequence of factorials: `1`

Comment: Thought that `Π` was a `П` (russian P)

Comment: @StanStrum Nope `Pi`, as in product