# Pseudo-deterministic number generator

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

## Task

Write a function/full program that will be able to produce two different sequences of integers in `[0, ..., 9]`. You will take an input `seed` to decide whether to output your `s`pecific sequence or the `c`ommon one. For that matter, you must choose one non-negative integer, let us call it `k`. When the input `seed` is equal to `k`, you will be dealing with your specific sequence `s`; when the input `seed` is anything else, you will be dealing with your common sequence `c`.

Both sequences should be such that the relative frequencies with which each digit appears tend to \$10\%\$. Be prepared to prove this if needed. Said another way, the running fraction of that digit's appearances needs to have a defined limit that equals \$0.1\$. Formally, this means that for every \$d \in \{0,...,9\}\$,

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{\left|\{i : i \in \{1\dots n\}, s_i=d\}\right|}{n} = 0.1$$

*Adapted from [What an Odd Function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/141315/what-an-odd-function)*

There should be one extra restriction your sequences should satisfy: when zipped together* to form a sequence `a` of terms in `[0, ..., 99]`, the relative frequency of each number should converge to `0.01` via a limit like the formula above.

<sup>*That is, the \$n\$th term of the sequence `a` is the two-digit number built this way: the digit in the tens place is the \$n\$th term of the sequence `c` and the digit in the units place is the \$n\$th term of the sequence `s`.</sup>

## Input

A non-negative integer representing the "seed", which you use to decide whether to output the common sequence or the specific one.

## Output

Your output may be one of the following:

- an infinite stream with the sequence (and you take no additional input);
- output the `n`th term of the sequence (by taking an additional input `n` that is `0`- or `1`-indexed);
- output the first `n` terms of the sequence (by taking an additional positive input `n`).

## Example pseudo-algorithm

Assuming I have defined `seed` as an integer, and for these choices I made for `s` and `c`:

```
input_seed ← input()
n ← input()
if input_seed = seed: print (n mod 10) # this is my sequence s
else: print ((integer div of n by 10) mod 10) # this is my sequence c
```

Both sequences output numbers in `[0, ..., 9]` and the frequency with which each digit appears tends to `0.1` as `n → infinity`. Similarly, zipping `c` and `s` together gives `n mod 100` so it is also true that as `n → infinity` we have that the relative frequency with which each number in `[0, ..., 99]` shows up goes to `0.01`.

Comment: so to clarify, when given any number I should print a specific sequence c which appears random, which would be the same sequence for all input apart from a specific N that I choose?

Comment: Can my sequence be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 repeated infinitely?

Comment: @SurculoseSputum here should be one extra restriction your sequences should satisfy: when zipped together* to form a sequence a of numbers in [0, ..., 99], the relative frequency of each number should converge to 0.01.

Comment: @CommandMaster If the other sequence is 10 0s, 10 1s, 10 2s, it'll work.

Comment: @Adám Regarding the "s.t.", I think it means "such that"/"so that". Although I was indeed wondering the same thing at first. Not a very commonly used abbreviation.. Apart from that I also have the same question as you: what is meant with 'infinite sequence' here (and what is the purpose if we only have `[0,9]` to output anyway)?

Comment: I suspect OP intended some pseudo-randomness here.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that random tag. Deleted my answer until the meaning of random is clarified.

Comment: @RGS Indeed, I've already deleted those two, but my third one about randomness hasn't been addressed.

Comment: @RGS Deleted my comment. In that case, could you please add an example of a valid \$seed\$, \$s\$, \$c\$, and perhaps \$c_{seed+1}\$, \$c_{seed+2}\$ (doesn't have to be optimal, just an example), since I don't understand it tbh..

Comment: Do I understand this correctly, that we have to write a PRNG with two possible functionally distinct seeds?

Comment: I'm confused, does "given an integer seed, always creates the same sequence" mean that different seeds are allowed to give different sequences, as long as each specific seed always gives the same thing? Or that they all give the same sequence regardless of the seed?

Comment: @xnor the first paragraph has been rewritten and I have included an example submission to help clarify things.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen check the example pseudo-alg I provided.

Comment: @Adám the use of "random" was misleading; it should be clear now what I mean.

Comment: Thanks, that clear it up. I still find it pretty convoluted though, not so much because of the explanation, but because the premise is pretty weird. It seems to me that really we're given a Boolean that tells us which of the two sequences to produce. And I can't imagine answers doing anything but converting to this bool as the first step. Like, the two-independently-uniform-sequences is a cool idea but it's too bad that the reader has to first process all the stuff in the first paragraph before they get to that.

Comment: @xnor that was pretty much what I wanted the challenge to be, "depending on an input seed, produce one of two independently uniform sequences" but I assumed that would be too unclear.

Comment: I think your example algorithm needs to do a mod-10 in the second case so that its results are from 0 to 9.

Comment: Are the probabilities/frequencies of 10%/0.01 roughly or exact? Since you use the phrases "_the relative frequencies with which each digit appears **tend** to 10%_" and "_the relative frequency of each number **should converge** to 0.01._", it seems to apply roughly. Reason I'm asking is the discussion in the 05AB1E answer, where the probability for the infinite sequence is indeed ~10%/0.01, but the count of `0` will always be at least 1 (and at most 10) behind on the count of the other digits, regardless of the sample size. The counts of the digits can never be the same, but it's still ~10%.

Comment: ^To clarify why: the 05AB1E answer will always output \$n\$ instead of \$\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{10}}\right\rfloor\$ for \$n<10\$, regardless of the \$seed\$, which is where this irregularity comes from of the `0` always being \$[1,10]\$ behind in terms of counts.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen The value `0.1` should be the exact value for the limit of \$\frac{\text{number of times d appeared before term n}}{n}\$ as `n` tends to infinity, for `d` in `[0, ..., 9]` for either sequence `c` or `s`. Similarly with `0.01` for the zipped sequence. The 05AB1E answer has the count of 0s lagging behind, but as `n → infinity` the limit above still gives the correct answer :)

Comment: @RGS Thanks for clarifying. I'll keep my comments in case anyone else thinks the same as I did.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

*Thanks @xnor for figuring out a really cool way to convert the seed to `-1` or `-2`, which saved 1 byte.*

```python
lambda s,n:`n+9`[2/~s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFYJ88qIU/bMiHaSL@uOPZ/Wn6RQqZCZp5CUWJeeqqGoY6hgaGmFZdCQVFmXolCmoaBTqamDpA2hNJGQPo/AA)

**Input**: The seed `s` (non-negative) and an index `n` (positive).
**Output**: The element at the nth index (the sequence is one-indexed)

If the seed is positive, the sequence is `0123456789` repeated infinitely.
If the seed is `0`, the sequence is: `1111111111 2222222222 ... 9999999999 0000000000` (where each digit repeats 10 times) repeated infinitely.

**How**

- `` `n+9` `` creates a string from a number that has at least 2 digits.
- `2/~s` evaluates to -2 if `s` is 0, or -1 if `s` is positive
- Thus `` `n+9`[2/~s] `` takes the last digit (unit digit) of \$n+9\$ if `s` is positive, or the second to last digit (ten digit) if `s` is 0.

Comment: `2/~s` also works and is shorter.

Comment: I admit I didn't actually figure this out. :-P I just brute-forced all short expressions. There was also `-2>>s` for a tie. Switching the two cases didn't give anything.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  <s>4</s>  3 bytes

```
ΘÍè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3IzDvYdX/P9vwGVqBgA)

Takes the seed then n and outputs the nth term, outputs different sequence for seed of 1

---

### Explanation

```
Θ                  - truthified (so 1 if input is 1, else 0) 
 Í                 - subtract 2 (so -1 if input is 1, else -2)
  è                - take this index of the nth term
```

Since 05AB1E uses modular indexing it won't go out of bounds, and `a[-1]` is the last element of a. Likewise `a[-2]` is the penultimate.

---

Alternatively to output an infinite sequence.

#### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
∞εIΘÍè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8c1s9z8043Ht4xf//BgA)

Comment: For the first 10 values this is indeed true, but let's say you take the first 200, then there are just 11 `0`s, but 21 of every other digit: [see here](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9vc2FiaWX//@KIns61UknOmMOofTIwMMKjOcOdwqL//zE). I think you have to add a leading `0` for inputs `n` below 10 first before reverting (i.e. with `т+RIΘè` or `0ìRIΘè`).

Comment: No I disagree.. You've just picked a specific value still in a small range which will do this.. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9vc2FiaWX//@KIns61UknOmMOofTIwOcKjOcOdwqL//zE "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: It's always going to be at most 10 behind @KevinCruijssen so as it tends to infinity it will tend to 0.1 probabilty...[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8c1uDPM/NOLyi1tQACA4ttjw899Ci//8NAQ "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: Although a valid point with it being just 1 behind for the `209` sample size, I was under the impression that the probabilities of 10% and 0.01 were exact for specific sample sizes, not roughly.. No matter the sample size, the count of all ten digits can _**never**_ be the same in your answer, since the `0` is always at least 1 (and at most 10) behind on the others. But OP does indeed use the terms "_tend_" and "_should converge_", which seems to apply roughly 10%/0.01, so maybe it indeed doesn't matter.. :S I'll ask OP to verify.

Comment: This looks valid to me. The challenge asks about the limit frequency of each digit or pair. Changing any finite number of entries can't affect this.

Comment: Ok, in that case I stand corrected. I'll keep my comments for now in case anyone else thinks the same as I did. ([And OP just clarified that it's indeed valid.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201764/pseudo-deterministic-number-generator/201767?noredirect=1#comment480139_201764))

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 24 bytes

```c
f(s,n){s=(s?n/10:n)%10;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcnBCsIwEIThe55iKBR2acSNR2PwRbxIJLIHV2l6K332mIow8MH8@fDMubVC1RuvNVG92jHI2XgMEremtuB1VyPG6sp7Bu2PIkEi9JKCdKdJGQ6fubdCw/jAbzcbPAqJV94Nf09djm5rXw)

***Input***: seed (\$s\$) and \$n\$.
***Output***: \$n^{\text{th}}\$ term zero-indexed.

For \$s=0\$ the sequence is: \$0,1,2,\dots,9,\dots\$
For \$s>0\$ the sequence is: \$\underbrace{0,0,\dots,0}_{10},\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_{10},\underbrace{ 2,2,\dots,2}_{10},\dots,\underbrace{9,9,\dots ,9}_{10},\dots\$

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 38 bytes

Takes Input [n,seed] and outputs nth term
Specific seed is 0

```
If[#2>0,#~Mod~10,Floor[#~Mod~100/10]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zMtWtnIzkBHuc43P6XO0EDHLSc/vygaxjXQNzSIjVX7H1CUmVei4JAebWKkYxjLhcw1gHIdlJQgDH2H6vRoZR2jWDV9h6DEvPRUByMDg1rsigxQFf3/DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>9</s> 5 bytes

```
§Ｓ⊕¬Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMOxxDMvJbVCwzOvoLQkuAQolq6hqaPgmZdclJqbmleSmqLhl18CkfYrzU1KLdLQBAHr//@NzRUM/@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as `n`, `s` and outputs the (1-indexed) third digit of `n` if `s` is zero otherwise the second digit of `n` (so somewhat similar to @ExpiredData's answer, although this was unintentional). The two sequences separately always output an exact 10% frequency after a power of 10 terms, while the combined sequence outputs an exact 1% frequency between the (0-indexed) 10th term and a higher power of 10 terms. Explanation:

```
    Ｎ   Input `s`
   ¬    Logical Not
  ⊕     Incremented
 Ｓ      Input `n` as a string
§       Cyclically indexed
        Implicitly print
```

Version that outputs the first `n` terms for each of the first `s` seeds:

```
ＥＩθ⭆Ｉη§Ｉλ⊕¬ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDDObG4RKNQU0chuAQolg4XygAKOZZ45qWkVkAEcoACnnnJRam5qXklqSkafvklGpmaYGD9/7@xgqGBgcF/3bIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7), 19 bytes

Takes input as `(seed)(n)` and returns the \$n\$-th term. The special seed is \$0\$.

```javascript
s=>n=>n/10**!s%10|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcrRCoIwFIDhe5/idBFubtmZt2bQc0gXslxMxIUbQVbPbqcgWIGwcc6@f11zbbwe7SVsBndqZ1PNvtoPdLYKs2zl1wofOBs3soBQwWEcmxtTyHNj@54hlxDUgheRx8GSq5LGjiYibUJwuCcAAWtP0dA3ZvlRiPKNqtYfVDEW9UQoWJqCAE3Xf5N2g3d9m/fuzLwELWHiyTOJmZc/z4B55@zAUpny/6SWUxGn@QU)

Comment: Does [this](https://tio.run/##dYrRCoJAEEXf/YrJF3cZk1lfzaDvEB9k01gRN3aXIKtvtykITBBmuHfOmb65NV47cw370Z7buStnXx5Hngp3HlX9pLmzTgSCEk7ONXehiGTWmWEQJFMIakvkG8IwVwXHgZOIuCJKeEQAgSrPtuM/YTCOZY1YfLiq9JerFc@riTmKJAEEzet/StvR26HNBnsRPgWdwiSjV7TEsvg7A2W9NaNI0kSuldpW@VLNbw "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") work for 16? Takes n as a string

Comment: @ExpiredData I think so. You may want to post it as a separate answer. (Note that you don't need the leading `+`.)

Comment: Ok thanks @Arnauld :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <sup><s>25</s></sup> 23 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Mitchell Spector](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59825/mitchell-spector)!!!

```bash
echo $[$2/($1?10:1)%10]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pcy9DYMwEAbQ/qb4CiOg8HEHXVJkkIgi/Fi4sSOgszy7owyAFClvgDe9jq24pk1lnbcI8zR91xh9qNy0rVTGksnFHR4@IAmziuT7EgkOAuNpiWGl9@7D6WAtaluxHDWSMg@S6bteBvpv0P8alA8)

***Input***: seed (\$s\$) and \$n\$.
***Output***: \$n^{\text{th}}\$ term zero-indexed.

For \$s=0\$ the sequence is: \$0,1,2,\dots,9,\dots\$
For \$s>0\$ the sequence is: \$\underbrace{0,0,\dots,0}_{10},\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_{10},\underbrace{ 2,2,\dots,2}_{10},\dots,\underbrace{9,9,\dots ,9}_{10},\dots\$

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by using `$[...]` instead of `$((...))`.

Comment: @MitchellSpector Nice one -  thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 15 bytes

```javascript
s=>n=>n[!s+1]|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYpBCoMwEEX3nmLqJgmxMnFrLfQc4kJSLRExJQmF2vbs6bRQsIIww//z3gztrfXamWvYT/bcxb6KvjpONPXOS9U8MfbW8YBQwcm59s4Vosh7M44cRQZBbYliQxjiqqQ4UCIiVSkFPBKAgLUn29MfNzJNRSNl@eGq1l@uVryoZ@KSMwYSNK3/KW0nb8cuH@2F@wx0BrNIXskSi/LvDJgP1kycZUysldpWxVLFNw)

If seed is 0 it will take the 3rd digit of the number, else it will take the 2nd digit of the number

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 16 bytes

```
^(0,.+).
$1
!`.$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP07DQEdPW1OPS8WQSzFBT@X/fwMdAy4DHRMjLkMgwxDIAAA) Link includes test cases. Takes input as `s,n` and outputs the second last digit of `n` if it has one and `s` is zero otherwise the last digit of `n`. The individual sequences are 10% of each digit but the combined sequence only approaches 1% after the 10th term. (I have a 16 byte answer in Retina 1 for which the combined sequence contains 1% of each pair.) Explanation:

```
^(0,.+).
$1
```

If `s` is `0` then delete the last digit of `n` unless that is its only digit.

```
!`.$
```

Output the last digit of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <sup><s>15</s></sup> 13 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Mitchell Spector](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59825/mitchell-spector)!!!

```
[A/]sa?0=aA%p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/z/aUT@2ONHewDbRUbXg/39DI2MFAwA)

***Input***: \$n\$ and seed (\$s\$).
***Output***: \$n^{\text{th}}\$ term zero-indexed.

For \$s>0\$ the sequence is: \$0,1,2,\dots,9,\dots\$
For \$s=0\$ the sequence is: \$\underbrace{0,0,\dots,0}_{10},\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_{10},\underbrace{ 2,2,\dots,2}_{10},\dots,\underbrace{9,9,\dots ,9}_{10},\dots\$

Comment: You can use `i` or `o` instead of `10`, saving 2 bytes.

Comment: @MitchellSpector Didn't like `i` or `o` but it worked with `A` - thanks! :-)

Comment: Sorry, I meant `I` or `O` (with capital letters), but `A` is even better.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 45 bytes

```
v=input('');rng(fix(~v(1)));randi(10,v(2),1)-1
```

`randi(N,n,1)` generates an n-length sequence of uniform random integers in the range 1,...,N. Taking two digits of the resulting sequence of realizations at a time, the required distribution follows naturally, which can be checked using the example code below.

```
N = 50000 ;
[h,x] = hist(10*(randi(10,N,1)-1) + (randi(10,N,1)-1), 100) ;
h = h/sum(h) ;
stem(x,h) ;
axis([0 10 0 0.1]) ;
```

`rng(fix(~s))` sets the random number generator seed to one if `s=0` otherwise to zero.

## Inputs

Read from the console in the format (incl brackets) "[s n]".

## Comments

- This method can be extended to generate limitless number of sequences which satisfy the required properties.
- Now compatible with several versions of MATLAB

Comment: Does this do a different sequence for every possible seed?

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter thank you! My mistake cost me one byte.

Comment: I don't know MATLAB, but I think you need to take `s` as an input somehow rather than expecting it to be stored in the variable `s`.

Comment: @xnor Thanks! It's done.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <strike>22</strike> <strike>19</strike> 17 bytes

Following earlier resolutions, this R code is producing two different sequences with the correct limiting frequencies whether \$s=0\$ (penultimate digits) or \$s\ne 0\$ (last digits):

```
1:n%/%10^(!s)%%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/pfbGtsbJ1na5hq/N/QKk9VX9XQIE5DsVhTFcj4/x8A)

As for checking whether or not the merged sequences work as well, one can run, e.g.,

```
summary(as.factor((10*(1:n%/%10%%10)+(1:n%%10))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
!←±⁰d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9odXNr/21vd1MsYOG5gOKCgcWAMjAwxYAz/yHihpDCseKBsGT//w) Gives a single term, given `seed` and `n` as arguments. `k` is equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

## [perl](https://www.perl.org/) -apple, 18 bytes

```
$F[0]&&chop;$_%=10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/FLdogVk0tOSO/wFolXtXW0OD/fwMFI2MuQxBhoGBoas5laA6mgBygqOG//IKSzPy84v@6iQUFOQA)

Prints the last digit of `n` for the special sequence (`c = 0`), otherwise, the penultimate digit of `n`. It doesn't quite work for single digit `n`'s, but since we only have to tend towards equal distribution, it doesn't matter what it prints.

Answer (score 0):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

(Port of the Charcoal answer.) How in the world can a 3-byter ever compress in the compressor‽

```
H≡
```

Uncompressed:

```
!)[
```

## Explanation

```
!   % Logical negate the first input.
 )  % Increment the negated input.
  [ % Cyclic index the second input by that result.
```